# Why does my array change its values inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble with an array that doesn't hold the final values it should, but I'm unsure what is causing this issue. As I log the values I can see that I'm storing what I intend for every tempArr[row][col], but when I log tempArr after the for loop is complete my values are not what they should be. With the code provided below, does anybody know where I'm going wrong?

```
let tempArr = new Array(3)
    .fill(new Array(3)
    .fill({
        color: 'white'
    }));

for(let row = 0; row < 3; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < 3; col++){
        console.log(board[row][col]);
        tempArr[row][col] = board[row][col]
        console.log(tempArr[row][col]);
        console.log("----");
        if(row === 2 && col === 2) {
            console.log(tempArr);
            done = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (done) break;
}
console.log(tempArr);
```

Comment: What's the intended output vs actual output?

Comment: What is `board`? Where is `done` defined?

Comment: kindly give your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your arrays have the same reference. Array.fill will fill the array with the same reference.

```
const arr = Array(3).fill({}); // [{}, {}, {}]
arr[0].hi = "hi";              // [{ hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }, { hi: "hi" }]
```

From the docs:

> If the first parameter is an object, each slot in the array will reference that object.

For understanding see the difference between the two outputs below.

In the first one: I am returning a new array for every row using map.
In the second one (which is same as your code), all your rows point to the same array instance.

```js
let tempArr = new Array(3)
    .fill(0).map((x) => new Array(3)
    .fill(0));
let x = 0;
for(let row = 0; row < 3; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < 3; col++){
        tempArr[row][col] = x++;
        }
    }


console.log(tempArr);


let tempArr2 = new Array(3)
    .fill(new Array(3)
    .fill(0));

let y = 0;
for(let row = 0; row < 3; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < 3; col++){
        tempArr2[row][col] = y++;
        }
    }


console.log(tempArr2);
```

Notice how the log here says `/**ref:2**/`. In chrome console, you will see the values, which will make it more clear. The output would be :

[image]